# Flake8 Errors not shown in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, flake8, linter

I have been using flake8 for linting but somehow it stopped showing me errors in the code in any of my workspaces (the squiggly underlines in the editor).

`flake8` is installed in my conda environment.

Here is my `settings.json`:

```json
{
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,

    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Args": [
        "--max-line-length=80",
        "--docstring-convention=google",
        "--verbose"
    ]

}
```

When I run `flake8` from the console, it does show me the errors.

I am using VS Code version 1.72.2 on Windows, and I installed flake8 version 5.0.4. Any idea what could be wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Open Command Palette and type in `Linter`. Select the option `Python: Select Linter` and it opens up all the available linters.
In the drop down, select `Flake8` and if required install it.

That should work now!

Answer (score 0):

Just add to `settings.json`:

```json
"python.linting.flake8Path": "full_path_to_env/bin/flake8"
```